# Is there an API for stripping audio(mp3) out of a video file (avi/divx/xvid/mpeg)?

Tags: video, audio, mp3, strip

Is there an API for stripping audio(mp3) out of a video file (avi/divx/xvid/mpeg)? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check out libffmpeg (FFmpeg [1])

[1]: http://ffmpeg.org/ FFmpeg

EDIT: check out for audio (de)muxing routines

Comment: thanks. but ffmpeg is complex. Is there a built in api/ program that just does audio stripping? thanks